# My VBA script crashes excel too much

Tags: vba, excel

I got a nice piece of vba code to pull data from other closed workbooks (which data structure and names will remain the same always)

The code practically allows the user to choose one of right workbooks and the code will do the rest, copying the relevante data over the workbook the user is currently working in.

I know the way this works is... not elegant, and there are surely better ways to do this, but I am sure the structure of the workbooks wont change anytime soon and if they do I tried to make sure to make the code as simple as possible for easy maintenance.

I am working with a module because through the workbook the user will repeat the same action over 4 times. The module takes three parameters, the worksheet it should seek (which will remain the same), the importRange (the columns I should take, from over 40 columns in a table or range in the workbooks, I need 4-6 columns. Like I said, the data structure will remain the same) and the destinRange (destination range, the range the code will copy the imported data to).

The following is an example of the parameters the I give to the module when the user clicks on a button in a sheet:

```
Dim currentWorkSheet As String
Dim importRange As String
Dim desinRange As String

currentWorkSheet = "Summary"
importRange = "Summary!C2:C500000,Summary!F2:F500000,Summary!G2:G500000,Summary!I2:I500000,Summary!W2:W500000"
desinRange = "A2:E500000"

ImportarInfo currentWorkSheet, importRange, desinRange
```

For some reason I cant understand, Excel always freezes after the code has pasted the data into the destination range. I tried changing things a bit but I cant just fix this.

```
Sub ImportarInfo(Worksheet As String, importRange As String, DestinRange As String)
Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook
Dim rngSourceRange As Range
Dim rngDestination As Range
Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-16", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa; *.xlsb"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
            Set wkbSourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("K1") = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
            Worksheets(Worksheet).Activate
            If Worksheet = "TTS_DETAIL" Then
                ConvertTableToRange
                On Error GoTo Help
                wkbSourceBook.Sheets(Worksheet).Rows("1:2").Delete
                ActiveSheet.Range("A:AQ").AutoFilter Field:=27, Criteria1:=Array( _
                "02", "23", "30", "33"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
            Else
                If Worksheet = "AVYXSummary" Then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("A:W").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<=700" _
                    , Operator:=xlAnd
                End If
            End If
            Set rngSourceRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select source range", Title:="Source Range", Default:=importRange, Type:=8)
            wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate
            Set rngDestination = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select destination cell", Title:="Select destination", Default:=DestinRange, Type:=8)
            rngSourceRange.Copy rngDestination
            rngDestination.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            wkbSourceBook.Close savechanges:=False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I did my research but I just cant find a problem similar to mine, in the sense of someone having problem with a vba code which objective is to accomplish something similar to mine.

The code imports around 5k-8k records

Comment: Is the 500,000 rows just as an example? Otherwise, have you tried turning ScreenUpdating, EnableEvents and DisplayAlerts off and then back on while it's running? It may provide some small speed boost

Comment: Take a look at defining ranges with `.Rows.Count` and `.End(xlUp)` or just `.End(xlDown)` depending on how the data is so that you aren't grabbing 500000 rows every time where they might not be necessary. ( I understand that they could be but will there always be 500000 rows in every load? )

Comment: The tables where I get the data from will definitely have over 400k rows of information, but after I filter them I get at most 10k rows of information I need. Is just, because those 10k rows are spread over the original 400k if I just set it to just grab 10k rows in the code I will just grab the first 10k of the 400k, but I miss the other records that are spread further.

Comment: I have not tried adding the screenupdating, enableevents and displayalerts like you said. I am afraid I am not familiarized with them, where should I add them? At the beginning of the code?